# Change the system date in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Azure App Service provides a [WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management#how-do-i-set-the-server-time-zone-for-my-web-app) setting that changes the local time for the Azure Web App.

I would like to do something like this, but change the system date and time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no you cannot.
The list of settings mentioning the timezone setting does not mention anything related to that either https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings.